# How do you "correct" a dependent variable for an independent variable?

Tags: regression, controlling-for-a-variable, variable

How do you "correct" a dependent variable for an independent variable (which shows a correlation with the dependent variable but is not a significant predictor in the model/regression analysis? TIA

Comment: The correlation analysis shows a significant effect but not the regression analysis?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by “correct” a variable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.